# How to get appjar's .saveBox directory and filename?

Tags: python, tkinter, appjar

Im trying to make a txt file creator using appjar.saveBox, but if the user sets a custom filename it cannot be grabbed. I want to grab the filename, so there can be content inside of the file.

Here's the code i tried:

```
def pressing(button):
    if button == "Create .txt file":
        app2.saveBox(title="File creator", fileName="", dirName="", fileExt=".txt", fileTypes="", asFile=True, parent=None)

app2.addButtons(["Create .txt file"], pressing)
```

Tried also making the .saveBox a variable, but all the output that came out was only

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/directory/file.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

But, i want only the directory and filename.

Comment: Change `asFile=True` to `asFile=False`, or remove `asFile=True`.

Comment: Ok, changing to `asFile=False` made it work.